# json_encode doesnt respond for getJson

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

I have an html page that would send json request to get the data from a server [though php-mysql]. I see that the response is not being received. I tried debugging through fiddler and could see that "The response does not contain valid json text.

My code is below

## html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" 
        type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function populateFruitVariety() {

    $.getJSON('serverside.php', 
               {fruitName:$('#fruitName').val()}, 
               function(data)  {

    var select = $('#fruitVariety');

    if(select.prop) {
        var options = select.attr('options');
    } else {
        var options = select.attr('options');
    }

    $('option', select).remove();

    $.each(data, function(val, text) {
        options[options.length] = new Option(text, val);
    });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    populateFruitVariety();
    $('#fruitName').change(function() {
        populateFruitVariety();
    });
});

</script>

<form>
    Fruit:
    <select name="name" id="fruitName">
        <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Banana</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
        <option>Pear</option>
    </select>
    Variety:
    <select name="variety" id="fruitVariety">
    </select>
</form>
</html>
```

## serverside.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="db_common";
$table_fruit_info = "fruit_info";
$tc_fruit_id = "fruit_id";
$tc_fruit_index = 'fruit_index';

$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") 
       or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$database") or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_GET['fruitName'])) {
    $fruit_id = $_GET['fruitName'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table_fruit_info
                WHERE $tc_fruit_id='$fruit_id'");
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $ret_fruitIndex = $rows[$tc_fruit_index];
    }
}
echo json_encode($ret_fruitIndex);
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). mysql is no longer supported

Comment: I don't understand the `if` statement in your JS. It sets `options` to the same thing in both branches.

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) -- you are passing raw, unfiltered, unvalidated user input directly into an SQL string. SQL injection is [very easy to fix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/168868). Consider [switching to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `$ret_fruitIndex` is just a string, which dosn't have an appropirate JSON representative.  In your while loop, you are overwriting the value for this variable with each pass, which I assume is not what you are wanting to do.

I assume you really want to so something like:

```
$ret_fruitIndex[] = $rows[$tc_fruit_index];
```

As an side you code is very vulnerable to SQL injection and you also should not be using teh `mysql_*` functions which are deprecated.  I would suggest using `mysqli_*` functions, PDO, or something more modern and secure.

With regards to your jQuery:  I am not sure what you are doing here:

```
if(select.prop) {
    var options = select.attr('options');
} else {
    var options = select.attr('options');
}
```

As there is not any difference in cases there.

I also believe your `each()` function is wrong. The parameters passed to the callback function will be the index value of data and the value for that index.

You logic should be to remove all options, than add new options based on data, so I don;t know why the `options` variable has any involvement in this callback function at all.

Comment: Thanks a million. I made $ret_fruitIndex[] and could see that json response comes to the html page [verified through alert(data)]. But the select option doesnt get filled with the data returned. Any problem in my javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You need an array of fruitnames, so replace 
    $ret_fruitIndex = $rows[$tc_fruit_index];

with 
    $ret_fruitIndex[] = $rows[$tc_fruit_index];

Comment: Thanks joyce, I made $ret_fruitIndex[] and could see that json response comes to the html page [verified through alert(data)]. But the select option doesnt get filled with the data returned. Do you see any problem in my javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0):

After fixing your PHP, change the JS callback to:

```
function(data)  {

    var select = $('#fruitVariety');

    select.empty();

    $.each(data, function(val, text) {
        select.append($('option', {value: val}).text(text));
    });

});
```

`options` is not a reference to the array in the DOM, it's a jQuery object, so adding to it doesn't update the DOM.